# Eigenvector Anomaly

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I'm trying to compute the eigenvectors for:

$$
M = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 4 \\
 4 & 100
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Both myself and Mathematica report the **eigenvalues** as:

$$
\lambda_1 = \frac{1}{2} \left(101+\sqrt{9865}\right) \approx 100.161 \\
\lambda_2 = \frac{1}{2} \left(101-\sqrt{9865}\right) \approx 0.838647
$$

But when I ask for **eigenvectors**, the answer changes depending on whether I input the numbers as integers or floating-point numbers.

When I ask for `Eigenvectors[{{1, 4}, {4, 100}}]` I get:

$$
v_1 = \left(\frac{1}{8} \left(-99+\sqrt{9865}\right), 1\right) \approx (0.0403383, 1) \\
v_2 = \left(\frac{1}{8} \left(-99-\sqrt{9865}\right), 1\right) \approx (-24.7903, 1)
$$

When I ask for `Eigenvectors[{{1.0, 4.0}, {4.0, 100.0}}]` I get:

$$v_1 \approx (0.0403055, 0.999187) \\ v_2 \approx (-0.999187, 0.0403055)$$

When I calculate [by hand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8ekh.jpg), I get a solution which matches the first query.

So, am I going crazy and overlooking some important maths (not unlikely, very tired...) or is this a bug?

Possible related issues?:

- [Difference In Eigenvectors](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26139/difference-in-eigenvectors)
- [eigenvector bug?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30333/eigenvector-bug)

Comment: 1) We do not discuss Wolfram|Alpha questions/issues here. They're explicitly off-topic. 2) The [tag:bugs] should be used only if the behaviour has been confirmed by the community as anomalous and a bug.

Comment: `Normalise/@...` on exact case, will get you same results as inexact case.

Comment: This is what Mathematica does.  I don't see Alpha referenced int the question.

Comment: @MarkAdler Did you follow the "query" links? :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it appears to be concerned with the behavior of Wolfram|Alpha.

Comment: If we edited the question to replace the W|A queries with Mathematica commands, the difference would remain and the question would be on-topic. But is that too radical a change from the original question?

Comment: Ah, no, I didn't follow the links.  Though I would argue that since Wolfram Alpha uses Mathematica (or the "Wolfram Language" as they are calling it now), then the links are just a convenient way to immediately see what happens in Mathematica without having to run it.  What's more, Wolfram Alpha can be used directly in Mathematica, and in fact is what is recommended to, for example, enter units.  So shouldn't all uses of Mathematica be on topic here, including those that start with an equals sign?  This subtle distinction on what is "off-topic" seems doomed to failure.

Comment: @MarkAdler I understand what you mean, but this was [discussed a couple of years ago](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/267/5) and the community agreed that such questions were off-topic (disclosure: I wrote the opinion there) and it's even in the [official FAQ](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). When I wrote that, the site was just a month old, but in the 2 years since, there have been several questions on W|A which were marked off-topic by users... this is actually the one rule that has been applied consistently! (continued...)

Comment: @MarkAdler One might call the rule a bit too hasty/premature, but it has worked well and no one has dissented thus far. You're certainly welcome to write an answer on meta if you strongly feel otherwise :) I'm aware that one can use the `WolframAlpha` function in _Mathematica_. I also addressed this in my answer — using W|A from inside M is fine as long as it is not trivial and designed just to work around this off-topic restriction.

Comment: @RahulNarain Since this behaviour is also displayed in _Mathematica_, feel free to replace them with the equivalent commands (preferably, using `Eigenvectors` instead of `WolframAlpha`) and throw in a vote to reopen. I'll chip in my vote as well if you do so :)

Comment: @rm-rf Well, no, I'd have a hard time seeing how anyone would feel strongly about such a thing.  It just seems a little odd since the two are so intimately related.

Comment: @MarkAdler Oh, I fully agree with that. It was just that the crowd that uses W|A exclusively for all kinds of purposes (from random Facebook graphs to baking measurements to the speed of an unladen swallow to homework assignments...) is generally not interested in learning _Mathematica_ and they're **not** the crowd that we want to invite and encourage on this site :) The rule is primarily to raise the barrier of entry to this site... [this](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/17785) is how the average ("good") W|A question looks like :D

Comment: @rm-rf: Done. I hope Peter doesn't mind.

Comment: @RahulNarain Thanks! It's now open :)

Comment: Not at all! Sorry I caused such consternation but I figured since Mathematica was being used by Wolfram the reasons might lie there. Seems I wasn't far off the mark. Thanks for moderating!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eigenvectors for inexact arguments are normalized:

```
Eigenvectors[{{1, 4}, {4, 100}}]
% // N
Normalize /@ %% // N
Eigenvectors[{{1.0, 4.0}, {4.0, 100.0}}]

(*
{{1/8 (-99+Sqrt[9865]),1},{1/8 (-99-Sqrt[9865]),1}}

{{0.0403383,1.},{-24.7903,1.}}

{{0.0403055,0.999187},{-0.999187,0.0403055}}

{{0.0403055,0.999187},{-0.999187,0.0403055}}
*)
```

Answer (score 5):

Eigenvectors are just a direction, so the ones you have are equivalent up to a multiplicative factor.  Both answers are correct.  The second one is normalized to length 1.